# get a Minimum Referenced Classes from set of Jars Using ProGuard

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

In My program i have to referenced 24 libraries right now.

**so i want to cut down  the size of the referenced jars, because i am sure that only few classes my program references.**

Someone tell me that i can use [Pro Guard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to accomplish my goal.

My first question is is that correct tool i am referring to ?

**i want that i will get all referenced classes from My class path so i can pack them in one jar and get rid of huge sizing problem of referenced JARS.**

So the second question is

**if the Pro Guard is the tool , how can i do it ? is there any specific command to perform tracing ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what ProGuard can do with its shrinking step. ProGuard's documentation explains how to use it. The [examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html) are a good start.

The optimization step and the obfuscation step can further reduce the size of the program, but you can disable them if you wish (with the options `-dontoptimize` and `-dontobfuscate`).